# C memory allocations

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char

I was wondering how the C compiler allocated memory for a character array you initialize yourself, for instance:

```
char example[] = "An example string";
```

If it was a single character it would be `8 byte`, so would the example be `17 bytes` or does it have more because it needs to the `\0`to finish it off?

Or does it overestimate how much memory it needs?

Comment: `example` is of 18 bytes , not 17 (Did you count the NUL-terminator?)

Comment: `8 byte` or `8 bit` you mean?

Comment: A string is  terminated by `\0` -null character, not by `\n`

Comment: `\0` char is the null character automatically added by compilator; whereas `\n` is the new line character, not used if not specified by the programmer.

Comment: So the NUL-terminator is always added if you set the array to a string literal and it is just all the individual characters of 8 bits/1byte each plus 1 byte for the null terminator?

Comment: Yes. String literals are already NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char example[] = "An example string";
    printf("%zu", sizeof(example));
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o proof proof.c
```

Returns:

> 18 *(bytes, not bits)*

Because of the `\0` character at the end of string

Answer (score 0):

The size of a null (`\0`) terminated string of `strlen` `n` is `n+1`. As you say, one extra for the null character.

If string litterals weren't terminated, standard calls like `strlen` could not work as they look for the terminating `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

A single character should use one byte.

A string has automatically the zero-terminator and needs one byte more than characters in the string. If you use `" "` the zero-terminator is always added.

You can try to work with `strlen` and `strnlen`.

```
char cSample = 'T'; // one byte

char caSample[] = "T" //two bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

size of the string will be 18 byte including '\0' character. but length will be 17.

eg:

```
char arr[]="";
```

here empty string is assigned but **it will have size=1 byte**, due to null character'\0'. and **length will be zero** for the example `string ""` .